# C# String.Substring equivalent for StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, substring, stringbuilder

StringBuilder does not appear to have a Substring(start, len) method... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The StringBuilder class has a special version of the [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyx7s61s(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes two arguments, exactly as *Substring(startIndex, length)*.

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("This is a Test");
 string test = sb.ToString(10, 4);
 Console.WriteLine(test);   // result = Test
```

Comment: you can also access the Length property of the StringBuilder if you were doing something like removing the last character from the string where you would normally use `.Substring(0, sb.ToString().Length -1`

Comment: Better doing it on the StringBuilder itself without converting it to a string and then recreating another string with one character less. _sb.Length--;_

Comment: mmm fair enough, a better example would be passing in non-zero for the start index where you want to filter out the first *and* last character. To be clear, my example above is what NOT to do.

Answer (score 1):

these are all ways you can get the desired substring:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
b.Append("some text to test out!");
string s = b.ToString(0, 6);
//or ....
char[] letters = new char[6];
b.CopyTo(0, letters, 0, 6);
string s1 = new string(letters);
//or
string s2 = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
   s2 += b[i];
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but the latter one is slower than molasses in January

Comment: lol yes it is,i just wanted to present all the options available:)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you dont want to build whole string (StringBuilder.ToString()) and get the substring:

```
  public static StringBuilder SubString(this StringBuilder input, int index, int length)
{
    StringBuilder subString = new StringBuilder();
    if (index + length - 1 >= input.Length || index < 0) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Index out of range!"); 
    }
    int endIndex = index + length;
    for (int i = index; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        subString.Append(input[i]);
    }
    return subString;
}
```

Comment: Interesting view of the question. Perhaps you could remove the loop and use simply `return new StringBuilder(input.ToString(index, length));`

Comment: @Steve - Yeah you are right, I didn't notice that stringBuilder.ToString takes arguments index and length.